# how to string field be unique mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unique

```
public class Sport
{

    public int SportID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

Key in this table is SportID.
I can create a more sports with a same name, but i don't like this

How to my Name of sport can be unique? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: `I can create a more sports with a same name, but i don't like this` what do you mean by this? creating them in the database? a bit more information is required here.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `Index` data annotation. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Index)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
[Index]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: The Index attribute was introduced in Entity Framework 6.1. If you are using an earlier version the information in this section does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

**SportID** would be unique ( for most of the cases - Primary key fetch from DataBase )

Wrt SportName to be unique you have take precaution ( Place Validation rule - Client/Server Side ) i would recommend for **RemoteValidation in MVC**.

[Remote Validation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/)

[Remote Validation Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll8VtDRj8L4)